# What the ios equivalent of android Log.v, Log.d, Log.i, Log.e, etc?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, xcode, nslog

What the ios equivalent of android Log.v, Log.d, Log.i, Log.e, etc. ? Also on android i use the Android device monitor and logcat to access the log of my phone, what i will need to use under ios ? Especially from the iphone simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift:

```
print("")
```

Objectve-C

```
NSLog(@"")
```

You can view the logs in the lower bottom corner of xcode. Refer the image below.
[image]

Comment: thanks nishith Singh, but i don't use directly xcode, is their any other way to see this log ?

Comment: does that log appear in release builds as well?

Comment: Yes if you want to turn off the logs in release build you can override the built in print function and do a check there for release or debug build

Answer (score 2):

Types of Logs:

```
OS_LOG_TYPE_DEFAULT
OS_LOG_TYPE_INFO
OS_LOG_TYPE_DEBUG
OS_LOG_TYPE_ERROR
OS_LOG_TYPE_FAULT

//example   
os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "This is a log message.");
```

For details please refer to [apple reference guide](https://developer.apple.com/reference/os/1891852-logging)